# ClassCastException when using two Dataframes in a UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I Am relativley new to both Object Orientend an Functional programming so please forgive me if I am asking a dumb question here. I have searched thoroughly and tried to find answer myself for hours but to no avail.

I am working withh Spark2 on scala an have the following problem.

I have two Dataframes both of which I would like to pass to a UDF which should output one resultant Dataframe. For simplicities sake I have created two "test" dataframes as input.

```
val seqs = List(("1234","abaab"), ("1235","aaab")).toDF

val actions = List(1,2).toDF
```

The actions list dataframe will be converted to an Array of Strings e.g.:

```
val actionsARR = actions.rdd.map(x=>(x.getInt(0)+96).toChar.toString).collect()
```

We then have a UDF to count the occurances of the actions in the seqs:

```
def countActions(sequence:String, actions:Array[String]):Array[Int] = {
  return actions.map(x => x.r.findAllIn(sequence).size)
}
```

put together with :

```
val results = seqs.map(x=>(x.getString(0), countActions(x.getString(1),actionsARR))).toDF("sequence_u_key","action_counter")
```

This works fine in the spark shell running one command after the other, I now try to embed the code in a further UDF which will accept Dataframes as input:

```
def testFun(seqsin:DataFrame, actionsin:DataFrame ): DataFrame ={

seqsin.map(x=>(x.getString(0), countActions(x.getString(1),actionsARR))).toDF("sequence_u_key","action_counter")

}
```

calling this with :

```
testFun(seqs,actions).show
```

works, however it is currently not yet using the Dataframe actionsin but the array allready created from it called actionsARR.

Of course I want it to take the actionsin Dataframe and convert it to the Array within the UDF , so I tried :

```
def testFun(seqsin:DataFrame, actionsin:DataFrame ): DataFrame ={

val acts = actionsin.rdd.map(y=>(y.getInt(0)+96).toChar.toString).collect()

seqsin.map(x=>(x.getString(0), countActions(x.getString(1),acts))).toDF("sequence_u_key","action_counter")

}
```

But when I call the function with my dataframes as input I get :

> testFun(seqs,actions).show 17/07/19 07:31:32 ERROR Executor: Exception
>   in task 0.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 64) java.lang.ClassCastException
>   17/07/19 07:31:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 38.0
>   (TID 64, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.ClassCastException
>
> 17/07/19 07:31:32 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 38.0 failed 1
>   times; aborting job 17/07/19 07:31:32 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task
>   1.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 65, localhost, executor driver): TaskKilled (killed intentionally) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted
>   due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 38.0 failed 1 times, most recent
>   failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 64, localhost, executor
>   driver): java.lang.ClassCastException
>
> Driver stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>   at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) 
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)   at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1958)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:935)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)   at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:934)   at
>   testFun(:44)   ... 52 elided Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException

Maybee I am doing something fundamentatly wrong by trying to pass two Dataframes to a function , coverting one to an array and then using them in the function ? or maybee I am missing something simple ?

Oh, I can succesfully create a function that takes a single Dataframe and converts and returns this as an array.

Any help would be appreciated

Best Regards

James

Comment: **First** - none of what you have here is a "UDF" - UDFs are functions passed to DataFrame operations that transform DataFrame values directly; They are nor (a) functions that _use_ DataFrames as arguments / return values, neither (b) functions used when transforming RDDs; You keep switching between DataFrames and RDDs which would not perform well, stick to one API as much as possible; **Second** - I ran your code and got no exception (it works), so I suspect it's a setup issue (e.g. conflicting Scala versions? Two different Spark versions in classpath? Dunno).

Comment: Hi Tzach, many thanks for your responce , clarification of terms and recommendations regarding sticking to one API :-) I will check regarding the setup as the environment had been installed with two spark versions.

Comment: Indeed I tried the code on a "clean" cloudera installation and it works as expected...I just need to find out what messed up my Virtual Machine :-)